# Tracking an object with a ROI around the location in the previous frame

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on a c++ system that tracks a drone via opencv motion detection. The problem occurs when there is a lot of untracked motion in camera sight. The system sometimes sees other motion and then thinks this is the drone that I'm trying to locate. The problem is that the drone then starts doing things it should not. So I'm trying to figure out if I can reduce the tracking field that my system won't make illogical decisions

EDITED: Is there a way to track the drone depending on a ROI around the position the drones was located in the last frame. So that my program only checks in a ROI where the drone could fly to within the time frame of 1 frame. So the tracker can not locate the drone at the other side of the camera view.

Comment: You can mask your picture before tracking your drone.

Comment: I'm fairly new to OpenCV and computer vision in general. And by masking you filter out the background or something?

Comment: It's really hard to say without knowing anything about the code you are using. But most of the opencv functions have a ```InputArray mask``` as parameter like ```calcHist``` for example